# Error: bad base-64 when decrypting a string Java

Tags: android, encryption, base64

I'm attempting to encrypt and encrypt strings (passwords). I'm trying to encrypt I've tried all Base64 encoding options and it continues to return bad base-64.

```
private String encrypt(String password) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec key = generatePasswordKey(databaseSetup.getAES());
    @SuppressLint("GetInstance") Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encodeBytes = c.doFinal(password.getBytes());

    return Base64.encodeToString(encodeBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}

private String decrypt(String password) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec key = generatePasswordKey(databaseSetup.getAES());
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(password, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    byte[] decryptedVal = c.doFinal(decodedBytes);
    String decryptedPassword = new String(decryptedVal);
    return decryptedPassword;

}

private SecretKeySpec generatePasswordKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes();
    messageDigest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = messageDigest.digest();

    return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

}
```

Comment: Problem is outside functions, string not stored correctly. If you would have created an MCVE you would have known this. Test your methods separately. And don't encrypt using ECB; don't suppress the warning but use a well defined mode instead of relying on defaults.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I apologize for my novice programming. I do plan on moving on to AES/CBC/pkcs5padding, but I appreciate the advice immensely. I have found that I was accidentally decoding before decrypting, I appreciate point out where my error could've possibly been, and I have found it and the error has now changed. I appreciate your input regardless.

Comment: You **should** decode before decrypting. Base 64 is for converting binary to text *and back*. The binary is the ciphertext, not the plaintext. I ran your program above without issue. You have created a new error because you broke your program.

Comment: I understand that I have to decode before decrypting. I apologize for not being clear. What I meant to say that before this method(before it's called), it was decoding it again before being run through the method, which was causing the bad base64

Comment: Ah, glad you found out. Dec dec dec eh?

Comment: Now I'm getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption as an error and I'm trying my best to debug it slowly and carefully as to not make another rushed post that is going to waste people's time